# org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.6.21', apply: false]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hey I just created a new project in android studio. I am getting this weird issue. Can anyone know why this is giving error.

**Error**

```
Build file '/Users/vmodi/AndroidStudioProjects/KtorApplication/build.gradle' line: 5

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.6.21', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.6.21', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.6.21')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
    at ...
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using latest bumblebee android studio. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `id("kotlinx-serialization")` in the build.gradle.kts(Module:app)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the settings.gradle file contains all the plugin repositories that you should have:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Also you may need to downgrade the kotlin version or upgrade the gradle version, there's a compatibility matrix of versions compatible between them.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html